# Apache Tomcat 9 openSSL error thrown on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, openssl

I believe I know how to fix this - by making the following change in the tomcat configuration from:

<Connector port="443" **protocol="HTTP/1.1"**
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" keyAlias="somealias" keystoreFile="" keystorePass="" keystoreType="Windows-My"/>

We need to define tomcat to use JSSE in the protocol by doing the following change:

Connector port="443" **protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"**
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" keyAlias="somealias" keystoreFile="" keystorePass="" keystoreType="Windows-My"/>

What I would like to know is to understand how to make this work with openssl - it seems like it shouldn't matter which implementation I use? Any insight would be appreciated.

OS Windows Server 2016

Java jre1.8.0_261

Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].

APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].

APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]

org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-443"]

> WARNING [main]
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init Error
> initializing SSL context
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.Base64$Encoder.encode(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.Base64$Encoder.encodeToString(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.addCertificate(OpenSSLContext.java:405)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init(OpenSSLContext.java:249)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1137)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:574)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1059)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:304)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) ...
>
> [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"]  [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
> ["https-openssl-nio-443"]  [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [42,116]
> milliseconds SEVERE
> [https-openssl-nio-443-exec-3]
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun Error
> running socket processor
> java.lang.Exception: cannot create new ssl
> at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.newSSL(Native Method)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.(OpenSSLEngine.java:214)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.createSSLEngine(OpenSSLContext.java:492)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLEngine(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:119)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:329)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:175)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)